# Which version of Lombok is compatible with Java 6

Tags: java, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I have legacy code in Java 6 with many getters and setters and I would like to clean my code with Lombok but I cannot change the Java version because the server's Java version is 6.

Comment: Java 6 is old enough to drive in my country (way past EOL), have you considered updating the server? You can still run old Java code on newer JVMs. It's a different matter if it's older Java code _loading_ other Java code, then you'd end up with a bytecode version mismatch. You can, of course, just compile the Java 6 project on a newer language version with likely minimal impact (`ConcurrentHashMap` usage might rear its head, amongst other small things).

Comment: I would be real nervous about making that kind of change to a legacy codebase.  You'd get much more "mileage" from upgrading the JVM version.

Comment: @Taylor There is no difference between writing a setter out by hand having lombok generate it. The class file would be bit for bit identical (other than debug info, such as the line number table and local var names, maybe). Lombok.jar is not now nor has it ever been a thing you need (and should not) put on your server. It must be there when you compile. And that's that.

Comment: Having said all that, yes, of course, using any EOLled JVM is a security issue waiting to happen, OP needs to update their JVM.

Comment: Yeah, that's more my point.  It's changing the window dressing on the Titanic.  Not trying to slag lombok.

Comment: I don't manage the servers, I deliver the application to run on an on-premise server that they don't intend to update soon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All versions of lombok, even the most recent one, still fully support java6.

SOURCE: I'm a core lombok contributor. Note that the test suite includes JDK6, still.

But, one caveat: If support for java6 somehow breaks (I doubt that'll happen as I do not know *how* that would happen, but lets say it does), we'll "fix" that by dropping j6 support unless fixing it is trivial.

Comment: I used Lombok in the last version (1.18.30) with Maven and Java 6 and it worked